# How do I stream contents of a socket file descriptor over bluetooth?

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

I have a few basic questions on how to do this relating to actually viewing the stream on another android phone. The recording phone uses the following function to record to the `BluetoothSocket` file descriptor:

```
private void Record() {
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(512 * 1000);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT);
        if (mBluetoothSocket != null) {
            try {
                Field reflectedPfdField = mBluetoothSocket.getClass().getDeclaredField("mPfd");
                reflectedPfdField.setAccessible(true);
                ParcelFileDescriptor mParcelSCStream = (ParcelFileDescriptor) reflectedPfdField.get(mBluetoothSocket);
                if (mParcelSCStream != null) {
                    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mParcelSCStream.getFileDescriptor());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Since socket file descriptors are not seekable**, we can't relatively do:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setDataSource(bluetoothFileDescriptor);
```

I've read on this [mattakis blog](http://www.mattakis.com/blog/kisg/20090708/broadcasting-video-with-android-without-writing-to-the-file-system) that we need to fix up the file descriptor stream that is sent over with socket file descriptor. He mentioned I need to manage the `mdat` atoms and also the file type header. *What parts of code do I need to change to fix these things.*

How can I handle the bluetooth stream over the socket, would buffering the content from the bluetooth's input stream, fixing up the header, and mdat atoms (*I don't really know what these are*), then...

then... how can I pass my modified raw stream to media player?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to pass a stream to MediaPlayer is to create your own HTTP server ([NanoHTTPD](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd) as an example) with [range request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233) support on the localhost of your Android device (127.0.0.1) and transfer your stream by means of uri `http://127.0.0.1:55555/...` to MediaPlayer. Android supports only mp4, 3gp and webm video formats and [moov atom](http://www.file-recovery.com/3gp-signature-format.htm) should be at the beginning of your stream to be played by MediaPlayer class.